# Prevent UITextView.typingattributes applying backgroundColor on linebreaks(\n) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to make a RichTextEditor in my app.

The users can change both foreground color and background color when they're editing.

Here's how I set typingAttributes:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    self.setTypingColor(foregroundColor: self.foregroundColor, backgroundColor: self.backgroundColor)

    return true
}
```

But I found that if the user inputs the `\n`, the editor will also apply background color to the whole lines.

[image]

Here's what I want it to be.

[image]

That is, I want it to apply these colors only on the characters, not the `\n`,  `\t` nor `\r`.

Is there a way to do it without creating an `AttributedString` by my self?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work in the simple case.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" { // better matching required
        self.setTypingColor(foregroundColor: .clear, backgroundColor: .clear)
    } else {
        self.setTypingColor(foregroundColor: self.foregroundColor, backgroundColor: self.backgroundColor)
    }
    return true
}
```

But the problem will probably persist when the user pastes a string into your text view in which case I think you may have to start handling the attributed string.

Comment: This is what I'm worrying about. The users may paste texts from web pages, notes or else. Isn't there any property that can change the behavior of the coloring?

Comment: I don’t know of any property. The only way I could think of doing this would be to manually editing the attributed string.

Comment: ok, thank you. Your answer is still useful while the `text.count == 1` is true.